# systemd unit processes are ignoring sticky bits (sgid) on dirrectories

Tags: unix, service, systemd

I have a user vopi under which a systemd service is started (user-mode). The service is a python script that should write a file to a shared directory under path `/usr/local/myfolder`

The group set to `myfolder` is `bot` and I set a sticky bit to make all files created inside beeing owned by group `bot`.

Currently permissions of myfolder are looks like

`drwxrwsr-x root bot ... myfolder`

User `vopi` is inclided in group `bot`

When I start the script like `python main.py` it successfully creates a file under `myfolder` and it have permissions `-rw-rw-r-- vopi bot ...`. However, when I call `systemctl --user start myservice` it tries to make a file with permissions `-rw-r--r-- vopi vopi` and fails (I figured this out by temporary setting a group `vopi` to `myfolder`

Why does my script running under systemd unit is ignoring sticky bit set on directory and why does permissions are not `-rw-rw-r--`?

I have tried to set `Group=` option in unit config but it didn't work. The service failed with error: `216 Group`

Answer (score 0):

> I set a sticky bit to make all files created inside being owned by group `bot`.

This suggests that adding a sticky bit makes file ownership and permissions to be *inherited* from the parent folder. That's not the purpose of sticky bits. Sticky bit is a **restricted deletion flag**.

The `man chmod` on Linux describes both its current function and history:

> The restricted deletion flag or sticky bit is a single bit, whose interpretation depends on the file type.  For directories, it
>   prevents unprivileged users from removing or renaming a file in the
>   directory  unless  they  own
>   the  file  or the directory; this is called the *restricted deletion flag* for the directory, and is commonly found on
>   world-writable directories like `/tmp`.
>
> For regular files on some older
>   systems, the bit saves the program's
>   text image on the swap device so it will load more quickly when run; this is called the sticky bit.

Your `216 Group` error comes from the fact that [`systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)  configuration doesn't have such *`[Unit]` Section Option* as `Group=`. It's a [`systemd.exec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) (*Execution environment configuration*) option that belongs to `[Service]` (, `[Socket]`, `[Mount]`, or `[Swap]`) sections:

> `User=, Group=`
>
> Set the UNIX user or group that the processes are executed as,
>   respectively. Takes a single user or group name, or a numeric ID as
>   argument.
>
> For system services (services run by the system service
>   manager, i.e. managed by PID 1) and for user services of the root user
>   (services managed by root's instance of `systemd --user`), the default
>   is `root`, but `User=` may be used to specify a different user.
>
> For user
>   services of any other user, switching user identity is not permitted,
>   hence the only valid setting is the same user the user's service
>   manager is running as. If no group is set, the default group of the
>   user is used. This setting does not affect commands whose command line
>   is prefixed with "+".

Comment: it is already in [Service] group